# Add $And to class serilization in .net

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, mongodb-query

I have two class that is used to build a json query against the updated date in a mungodb database the json produced when the class is serialized I get the json:

```
{
   "_updatedAt":{
      "$gte":{
         "$date":"2015-10-29T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "$lt":{
         "$date":"2015-11-28T00:00:00Z"
      }
   }
}
```

The json string required has been changed following an update and now requires `And` operator to be used in the json as in:

```
{
   "$and":[
      {
         "_updatedAt":{
            "$gte":{
               "$date":"2015-10-29T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "$lt":{
               "$date":"2015-11-28T00:00:00Z"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am unable to see how I could alter my existing code to achieve this and can find no documentation.  How would I do this?

```
Public Class JobRootObject
   Public Property _updatedAt() As UpdatedAt
        Get
            Return m__updatedAt
    End Get
    Set(value As UpdatedAt)
        m__updatedAt = value
    End Set
    End Property
    Private m__updatedAt As UpdatedAt
End Class

Public Class UpdatedAt
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="$gte")> _
    Public Property gte() As Gte
        Get
            Return m_gte
        End Get
        Set(value As Gte)
            m_gte = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_gte As Gte
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="$lt")> _
    Public Property lt() As lt
        Get
        Return m_lt
        End Get
        Set(value As lt)
        m_lt = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_lt As lt
End Class
```